# Usando Angular "track by $index" com paginação, filtro e ordenação

Tags: angularjs, paginação, filtro, order-by

bom dia!

Estou tendo um baita problema ao tentar utilizar a Smart Table, com paginação, filtro e pesquisa em minha tabela.

Eu estava com a tabela funcionando quando convertia um JSON que consumia por uma requisição para objeto. No caso, eu fazia:

```
$scope.estoque = JSON.parse(data.data);
```

O problema veio quando precisei de incluir paginação, ordenação e pesquisa. Então utilizando a [Smart Table](http://lorenzofox3.github.io/smart-table-website/), que até então vinha atendendo no que eu precisava, isso, enquanto não precisou ordenar e nem pesquisar em uma tabela.

No caso, para utilizar as funcionalidades da mesma, o meu array da tabela não pode ser objeto como era anteriormente, precisa ser JSON. Que no caso possui o formato abaixo:

```
 $scope.estoqueJSON = data.data;

[
  {
    "EstoqueId": 553,
    "DescricaoEstoque": null,
    "NomeMaterial": "Cabo de Fibra Óptica 04FO Multimodo - Indoor / Outdoor - 62,5/125 Furukawa",
    "CodigoMaterial": "100",
    "Ni": "",
    "QtdMaterial": 3.0,
    "QtdMin": 0.0,
    "Unidade": "m",
    "MaterialId": 1
  }
]
```

Seguindo o que fala no site da smart table e do AngularJS 1, criei então a tabela da seguinte maneira:

```
<table st-table="estoqueStr" st-set-filter="myStrictFilter" class="table table-striped table-responsive">
                <thead style="text-align:center;">
                    <tr>
                        <th st-sort="CodigoMaterial" style="width:20px; font-weight:bold; text-align:center;">Código</th>
                        <th st-sort="Ni" style="width:20px; font-weight:bold; text-align:center;">Ni</th>
                        <th st-sort="NomeMaterial" style="width:20px; font-weight:bold; text-align:center;">Material</th>
                        <th st-sort="Unidade" style="width:20px; font-weight:bold; text-align:center;">UNI.</th>
                        <th st-sort="QtdMaterial" style="width:20px; font-weight:bold; text-align:center;">Qtd</th>
                        <th st-sort="QtdMin" style="width:20px; font-weight:bold; text-align:center;">Qtd Min.</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th style="width:20px;">
                            <input style="text-align:center;" st-search="CodigoMaterial" placeholder="Código material" class="input-sm form-control" type="search" />
                        </th>
                        <th style="width:20px; text-align:center;">
                            <input style="text-align:center;" st-search="Ni" placeholder="Ni" class="input-sm form-control" type="search" />
                        </th>
                        <th style="width:auto; text-align:center;">
                            <input style="text-align:center;" st-search="NomeMaterial" placeholder="Nome material" class="input-sm form-control" type="search" />
                        </th>
                        <th style="width:10px; text-align:center;">
                            <input style="text-align:center;" st-search="Unidade" placeholder="Unidade" class="input-sm form-control" type="search" />
                        </th>
                        <th style="width:10px; text-align:center;">
                            <input style="text-align:center;" st-search="QtdMaterial" placeholder="Qtde atual" class="input-sm form-control" type="search" />
                        </th>
                        <th style="width:10px; text-align:center;">
                            <input style="text-align:center;" st-search="QtdMin" placeholder="Qtde mínima" class="input-sm form-control" type="search" />
                        </th>

                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="" class="">
                    <tr ng-repeat="e in estoqueJSON | filter : paginate | orderBy:sortType:sortReverse | filter:searchField track by $index">
                        <td ng-repeat-start="item in e.value"></td>
                        <td style="text-align:center;">{{item.CodigoMaterial}}</td>
                        <td style="text-align:center;">{{item.Ni}}</td>
                        <td>{{item.NomeMaterial}}</td>
                        <td style="text-align:center;">{{item.Unidade}}</td>
                        <td style="text-align:right; color:black;">
                            <span e-form="tableform" editable-number="e.QtdMaterial" onbeforesave="checkQtdEstoque(e, $data)">{{item.QtdMaterial}}</span>
                        </td>
                        <td style="text-align-last:right; color:black;" ng-repeat-end>
                            <span editable-number="e.QtdMin" e-form="tableform" onbeforesave="checkQtdMin(e, $data)">{{item.QtdMin}}</span>
                        </td>

                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

Não sei porque diabos não da erro e também não exibe os dados do JSON. >( Alguém sabe me dizer que navalhada estou fazendo ? Muito obrigado!

AngularJS: 1.3

Answer (score 0):

Quando você usa o Smart Table, as diretivas `st-sort` e `st-search` fazem o serviço pra você - não precisa incluir o `filter` e `orderBy` do `ngRepeat`. Também não precisaria usar o `track by`, já que esse é util para vincular uma propriedade a um `ngModel`. Referência: no próprio exemplo do [site da biblioteca](http://lorenzofox3.github.io/smart-table-website/), não consta os termos no `ng-repeat`:

```
<tr ng-repeat="row in displayedCollection">
            <td>{{row.firstName}}</td>
            <td>{{row.lastName}}</td>
            <td>{{row.birthDate}}</td>
            <td>{{row.balance}}</td>
```

Quanto ao JSON, sempre se utiliza objetos para as funcionalidades, enquanto o formato JSON é utilizado apenas para armazenamento e transferência de dados. Como JSON, a variável contem apenas uma string e seria complexo buscar os dados internamente. Cito de novo o site da biblioteca como exemplo:

```
scope.rowCollection = [
    {firstName: 'Laurent', lastName: 'Renard', birthDate: new Date('1987-05-21'), balance: 102, email: 'whatever@gmail.com'},
    {firstName: 'Blandine', lastName: 'Faivre', birthDate: new Date('1987-04-25'), balance: -2323.22, email: 'oufblandou@gmail.com'},
    {firstName: 'Francoise', lastName: 'Frere', birthDate: new Date('1955-08-27'), balance: 42343, email: 'raymondef@gmail.com'}
];
```